# query on relationship to get attribute on the base of maximum value

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get the project current stage with the following relationships.

The project haveMany TaskGroup.
TaskGroup haveMany Setting.
'stage' is the attribute of the 'Setting' Model.

I'm trying to get the maximum id of task group which is assigned in the project and its setting will have its stage.

This code is working fine but this query is not optimized.

```php
//Project.php

public function getStepsAttribute()
{
    $id = $this->task_groups()->where('assigned',true)->max('id');

    if (is_null($id)){
        return 0;
    }

    return TaskGroup::find($id)->setting->step;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `orderBy` with `first()` and wrap a `double optional` here to ensure you don't get `property of undefined` errors:

```
return optional(optional($this->task_groups()->where('assigned', true)->with('setting')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first())->setting)->step;
```

You will receive the `step` if the model exists, otherwise `null`.

This has 2 advantages and 1 disadvantage:

**Advantages**

1. Eliminates an additional query
2. Applies eager loading to solve n..1

**Disadvantages**

My god that is some ugly code.

Comment: TaskGroup model will always have Setting record so i just removed optional.


return $this->task_groups()
            ->where('assigned', true)
            ->with('setting')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->first()->setting->step ?? 0;